# Best install route for a server?

Tags: networking, server, samba, ftp, transmission

I have an old optiplex system which i want to use as an FTP and Media server. I'm wanting to get more into linux so I'm wondering a few things

1. Would NOT running a GUI allow more room for the CPU and GPU to focus on other things?
2. Would I be able to set up a system where I have two ethernet controllers, and use them in a bridged mode? (Like Microsoft's Windows Bridge Mode)
3. I need to run Telnet (SSH), FTP (vsftpd), Transmission (Bit-Torrent), Subsonic, Apache and Serviio as well as a SAMBA client for use with a Media drive almost 1TB in size

Is all this doable from a command line perspective... I know that i can set up FTP first to aid in setting up of different things such as configurations etc. I just need to know if it's feasable

Thanks alot, sorry if I duplicated questions or w.e, I'm new to this site.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't need the GUI/Window manager don't install it.
2. You can run two ethernet controllers, and you can bridge them.
3. You can do all of that.

You've got a big thumbs up from me!